# Are Doctrine DBAL methods secure from SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

Doctrine's documentation tries to address security and SQL injections well, but I still can't figure it out. I am particularly interested in their methods, like `delete()`, `insert()`, and `update()`. For example:

```
$app['db']->insert('user', array('username' => $username,'email' => $email));
```

Are parameters being bound behind the scenes, or is this unsafe?

Comment: Here is what I tried to read: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/security.html